# Register a device as Direct Mode capable? (VR Headset Developers [GameWorks VR])

Tags: nvidia, oculus, virtual-reality, nvapi

Hi I'm looking for info about registering a custom display as "Direct Mode" compatible.

I have been going over the "VR Headset Developers" SDK and see example code for getting existing Direct Mode displays but no docs for registering one in the system as "Direct Mode" compatible. How do the NVidia drivers / "VR Headset Developers" API know what is a "Direct Mode" display?

Is this done in the EDID? The Oculus drivers seem to be using the EDID to find a "Rift DK2" display and then telling the system (NVidia drivers) that display is "Direct Mode" compatible... but as to how is the question I'm failing to find info on.

Any help or direction on this matter would be much appreciated.
If there is a better forum to be asking this on please direct me to that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the documentation for it as it was in the "release notes". Odd place for documentation.

The DOCS for this should really be added in the "NVIDIA Direct Mode Programming Guide.pdf" file and NOT just the "Direct Mode Release Notes.txt".

Comment: What was the answer, or where can `Direct Mode Release Notes.txt` be found?

Comment: Its located in: "direct_mode_dx/Readme.txt" QUOTE: "To recognize a VR display...". If you have the NDA version of the VR SDK you can find it.

Comment: It's been quite some time since 2016. Is this still under NDA? I'd like to also make a display mimic Direct Mode by modifying the EDID, so I can try outputting audio over HDMI to an Atmos receiver without any video from Windows.